# Get current wifi signal strength using python

Tags: python, wifi

I wanted to ask, if there is an easy way to get the WIFI strength of the current connected WIFI using python. I really just need the strength so i can differentiate between the states "not connected", "low-", "medium-", "high-" and "max connection".